# CURL not working in android

Tags: android, curl, android-ndk

I managed to compile curl using `NDK-RC10` to using in Android.
I got crash after following steps:

```
 1. push curl to /system/bin

 2. push curl.so to /system/lib

 3. run curl

 4. output:[1] + Stopped (signal)     curl
```

I check logcat, find:

> /DEBUG   (  122): backtrace:
>
> I/DEBUG   (  122):     #00  pc 00000000
>
> I/DEBUG   (  122):     #01  pc 0000483b  /system/bin/linker
>
> I/DEBUG   (  122):     #02  pc 000209d0  [stack]

what happened? how should I fix this?

I have `libz/libc/libssl` in `/system/lib`.

Comment: Have you tried using addr2line to decode the stack trace?